# Exibir Dialogo (Materialize) com ajax sem clicar no botão

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Galera, estou montando um sistema de tickets e decidi trocar a mensagem de ticket fechado de um `alert` para um dialog, seria o [toast](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html) do materialize.com. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer ele retornar já executado, sem ter que clicar no botão para isso como no site do materialize.

O código em java/ajax é esse.

```
$(function() {
            $(".fechar").click(function(){
                var element = $(this);
                var select_ticket = element.attr("close");
                var select_table = element.attr("ticket_table");
                var mail = element.attr("mail");
                var info = {
                    'close': select_ticket,
                    'ticket_table': select_table,
                    'mail': mail
                }
                if(confirm('Tem certeza que deseja fechar o ticket?'))
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "assets/inc/del/ticket.php",
                        data: info,
                        success: function(){
                            alert("Fechado com sucesso!");
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Como você está invocando esse `dialog`?

Comment: No site do materialize, eles dão esse código ` <a class="btn" onclick="Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 3000, 'rounded')">Toast!</a>` porém precisa ter um `onclick` para executar. Só que a minha intenção é que ao fazer a alteração no banco ele já retornar o `dialog` executado, sem haver a necessidade de clicar no botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta substituir `alert("Fechado com sucesso!");` por `Materialize.toast('Fechado com sucesso!', 4000)`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
     Materialize.toast('Ticket Fechado!', 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: Mais simples impossível. Obrigado cara.